# How to get barcodes in seq, two next to eachother. Jasper iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm designing barcode labels in Jasper iReport. It's 2 labels next to each other. At the moment I have it like this:

[image]

As you can see its the same barcode numbers next to each other. I want it to look like this:

[image]

So instead of 2 of the same barcode numbers next to each other I need unique ones right through. Not sure how to tackle this. Can someone help please?

Here is the code I use:

```
select to_char(pallet_id_no_seq.nextval) as barcode 
from dual 
connect by level <= $p{quantity}
```

As you see here above the query has a parameter in that I can use to choose how many barcodes I want to print in the Detail Band of Jasper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
 SELECT to_char(pallet_id_no_seq.nextval) as barcode 
 FROM (
      SELECT * FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= $P{quantity}
  )
```

In iReport:
Right click your report name in Report Inspector and choose Page Format. Change your number of columns to 2 and save. Right click the report again and choose Properties. Here you might need to change the print order to horizontal -- test it and see how that looks.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with the SQL. I need to know how to get the barcode numbers in sequence in iReport.

Comment: Are you looking for formatting/print order help? I edited my answer above.